# Записать данные из текстового файла проекта в массив C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть В ПРОЕКТЕ есть текстовый файл в папке с ресурсами .Мне надо считать с него данные и записать в переменную. Нужно чтобы работало У ВСЕХ. Система Windows.
В файле хранятся важные данные и создавать его на других системах не ахти.
Нужно,чтобы при каждом запуске программы данные считывались из проекта
https://prnt.sc/uscgwm

Comment: Это вас IDE какая-то в заблуждение вводит?

Comment: visual studio  ;/

Comment: https://mklimenko.github.io/english/2018/06/23/embed-resources-msvc/

Comment: Помогло=),все получилось. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Неплохо было бы, если бы вы оформили полноценный ответ на базе того, что у вас получилось)

Comment: мне нужно было чтобы создавался .bat файл из текстового файла с ресурсами,вот получилось у меня=). ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ВАМ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool GetFileToArray(std::string FileName, std::vector<std::string> &VectorOfSting){

    // Открываем файл
    std::ifstream in(FileName.c_str());

    if(!in){
        std::cerr << "Не удается открыть файл : " << FileName << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Считываем следующую строку из файла до конца.
    std::string str;
    while(std::getline(in, str)){
        // если размер строки больше 0 то пушим в массив VectorOfSting
        if(str.size() > 0){
            VectorOfSting.push_back(str);
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Файл пуст" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    in.close();
    return true;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> VectorOfSting;

    bool result = GetFileToArray("C:\\Drive\\Cpp\\example.txt", VectorOfSting);

    if(result){

        for(std::string & line : VectorOfSting)
            std::cout <<line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: нужно чтобы у всех работало=(. Изменил вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```
# cat data.txt
Hello world
# objcopy --input binary \
          --output elf32-i386 \
          --binary-architecture i386 data.txt data.o

# gcc main.c data.o && ./a.out
Hello world

# cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char _binary_data_txt_start;
extern char _binary_data_txt_end;

main()
{
    char*  p = &_binary_data_txt_start;

    while ( p != &_binary_data_txt_end ) putchar(*p++);
}
```

<sub>Источник: [Embedding a File in an Executable, aka Hello World, Version 5967
by Mitch Frazier on June 12, 2008](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967)</sub>